# How do we number multiple slides with same number in beamer?

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

How to have a common number for multiple slides in beamer? For example, in the following, I want to have same number for slides showing $f(a,b)=a^2$, $f(a,b)=a^2 + 2ab$ and  $f(a,b)=a^2 + 2ab + b^2$, such that when I go through the slides during  presentation, the audience sees on the changes in this function and nothing else.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,aps,umbc4,9pt,colorBG,slideColor]{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}\justifying % left-right alignment
\usepackage{txfonts}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=12pt, text margin right=12pt}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left, leftskip=5mm]
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\newcommand{\backupbegin}{
    \newcounter{finalframe}
    \setcounter{finalframe}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
    \setcounter{framenumber}{\value{finalframe}}
}
\newcommand{\dprime}{\prime \prime}

\date{}
\title[ Title ]{\huge\textcolor{green}{Title}}
%\subtitle{subtitle here}
\author[Name]{ \large{\textcolor{blue}{Name } }}
\institute[MIT]{ {\textcolor{blue}{Institute}}\\
    {\textcolor{blue}{Inst. Address1}}\\
    {\textcolor{blue}{Inst. Address2}}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{equation*}
             f(a,b) = a^2
        \end{equation*}     
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
    f(a,b) = a^2 + 2ab
\end{equation*}     
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation*}
        f(a,b) = a^2 + 2ab+b^2
    \end{equation*}     
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look in the overlay features of beamer. Then all content will be on the same slide (number). For example \pause

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

- Have a look at the so-called `overlay` features of the [`beamer` class](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).
- I use `\only<>{}` in the example below.
- By the way, the code you provided (thanks for that) contains too much information that is not needed in order to understand your problem. Next time, please [keep it simple :)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
% 1
\only<1>{
    \begin{equation*}
             f(a,b) = a^2
        \end{equation*} 
}
% 2
\only<2>{
    \begin{equation*}
             f(a,b) = a^2 + 2ab
        \end{equation*} 
}
% 3
\only<3>{
    \begin{equation*}
             f(a,b) = a^2 + 2ab+b^2
        \end{equation*} 
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Screenshots of the [`beamer` Class](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) Manual

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]